# How to use Mosquitto auth plugin with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, mqtt, mosquitto

I am writing a server on PostgreSQL and Mosquitto MQTT. It became necessary to use the MQTT authorization of clients using the PostgreSQL database.

I can't find any instructions or even an explanation of how to use the plugin or configure it. Any of my attempts led to errors or just a lack of result.

Thats my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:14.8-alpine3.18
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "max_connections=50"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_buffers=1GB"
      - "-c"
      - "effective_cache_size=4GB"
      - "-c"
      - "work_mem=16MB"
      - "-c"
      - "maintenance_work_mem=512MB"
      - "-c"
      - "random_page_cost=1.1"
      - "-c"
      - "temp_file_limit=10GB"
      - "-c"
      - "log_min_duration_statement=200ms"
      - "-c"
      - "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=10s"
      - "-c"
      - "lock_timeout=1s"
      - "-c"
      - "statement_timeout=60s"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements"
      - "-c"
      - "pg_stat_statements.max=10000"
      - "-c"
      - "pg_stat_statements.track=all"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ../2. Init Database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mosquitto/init-mqtt-auth-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mqtt-auth-db.sh
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${DATABASE_USER} -d ${DATABASE_NAME}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    networks:
      - postgres

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:7.2
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PG_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PG_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: "False"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1G
    networks:
      - postgres

  mqtt-broker:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    user: mosquitto
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
      - ./mosquitto/config/password.txt:/mosquitto/password.txt
      - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
      - data:/mosquitto/data
    ports:
      - target: 1883
        published: 1883
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 9001
        published: 9001
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      mqtt-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.10.10

  mqtt-pub:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    command: sh -c "mosquitto_pub -h mqtt-broker -t test -m 'Hello World' -u Frog -P 1234"
    depends_on:
      - mqtt-broker
    networks:
      mqtt-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.10.11

  mqtt-sub:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    command: sh -c "mosquitto_sub -h mqtt-broker -t test -u Frog -P 1234"
    depends_on:
      - mqtt-broker
    networks:
      mqtt-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.100.10.12

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  pgadmin-data:
  data:
    name: "mqtt-broker-data"

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

  mqtt-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.100.10.0/24

  postgres-data:
```

Please help me set up PostgreSQL and Mosquitto.

I tried to run it on a Linux virtual machine, but I got this error:

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/mosquitto-auth-plug$ sudo nano config.mk
user@user-virtual-machine:~/mosquitto-auth-plug$ make
Selected backends:         PostgreSQL
Using mosquitto source dir: mosquitto-2.0.18/
OpenSSL install dir:        /usr

If you changed the backend selection, you might need to 'make clean' first

CFLAGS:  -Imosquitto-2.0.18//src/ -Imosquitto-2.0.18//lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror -DBE_POSTGRES -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/include
LDFLAGS:  -Lmosquitto-2.0.18//lib/
LDADD:   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpq -L/usr/lib -lcrypto -lmosquitto

cc -Imosquitto-2.0.18//src/ -Imosquitto-2.0.18//lib/ -fPIC -Wall -Werror -DBE_POSTGRES -I`pg_config --includedir` -I/src -DDEBUG=1 -I/usr/include   -c -o auth-plug.o auth-plug.c
auth-plug.c:502:5: error: conflicting types for ‘mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check’; have ‘int(void *, const struct mosquitto *, const char *, const char *)’
  502 | int mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check(void *userdata, const struct mosquitto *client, const char *username, const char *password)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from auth-plug.c:36:
/usr/include/mosquitto_plugin.h:356:24: note: previous declaration of ‘mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check’ with type ‘int(void *, struct mosquitto *, const char *, const char *)’
  356 | mosq_plugin_EXPORT int mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check(void *user_data, struct mosquitto *client, const char *username, const char *password);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
auth-plug.c:601:5: error: conflicting types for ‘mosquitto_auth_acl_check’; have ‘int(void *, int,  const struct mosquitto *, const struct mosquitto_acl_msg *)’
  601 | int mosquitto_auth_acl_check(void *userdata, int access, const struct mosquitto *client, const struct mosquitto_acl_msg *msg)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from auth-plug.c:36:
/usr/include/mosquitto_plugin.h:339:24: note: previous declaration of ‘mosquitto_auth_acl_check’ with type ‘int(void *, int,  struct mosquitto *, const struct mosquitto_acl_msg *)’
  339 | mosq_plugin_EXPORT int mosquitto_auth_acl_check(void *user_data, int access, struct mosquitto *client, const struct mosquitto_acl_msg *msg);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
auth-plug.c:752:5: error: conflicting types for ‘mosquitto_auth_psk_key_get’; have ‘int(void *, const struct mosquitto *, const char *, const char *, char *, int)’
  752 | int mosquitto_auth_psk_key_get(void *userdata, const struct mosquitto *client, const char *hint, const char *identity, char *key, int max_key_len)
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from auth-plug.c:36:
/usr/include/mosquitto_plugin.h:384:24: note: previous declaration of ‘mosquitto_auth_psk_key_get’ with type ‘int(void *, struct mosquitto *, const char *, const char *, char *, int)’
  384 | mosq_plugin_EXPORT int mosquitto_auth_psk_key_get(void *user_data, struct mosquitto *client, const char *hint, const char *identity, char *key, int max_key_len);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [<встроенное>: auth-plug.o] Ошибка 1
```

I also tried to do it on Docker, but I didn't get any results.

Comment: Which "auth plugin" are you using? (there are a few). I'm guessing [`jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug`](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug) which was archived in 2019? (if so it's likely Mosquitto has changed in the interim period, especially with the V2 release you are using).

Comment: @Brits Yes, I've tried using this plugin. Maybe there is some other way?

Comment: Requests for libraries/tools are are [off topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but the "Mosquitto Enhancements" section of the [download page](https://mosquitto.org/download/#mosquitto-enhancements) might suggest an option (or you could always write your own plugin)...

Comment: @Британцев The question wasn't originally a library request, so it's on topic. 
There is a plugin on the page, but I tried to use it, it didn't work out, so I ask for an explanation. 
I can't write my own plugin, I don't have enough knowledge. Besides, if there is a ready-made one, then why not use it

Comment: You did not state which plug-in you are using (I'm still guessing its the outdated one I mentioned earlier; `mosquitto-go-auth`, mentioned on the downloads page, is a totally different plugin). Please update the question (and clearly state which plugin you are working with). I did not say your question was off topic (but did suggest that your comment is); using a ready-made plugin is fine; asking us to suggest one is not (but I did suggest one anyway :-) ).

Comment: @Brits I tried using the plugin you mentioned in the first comment, which is outdated. It gives an error, which I showed with a screenshot. I also tried mosquitto-go-auth. There is a docker file there that will allow you to test its operation. However, when I ran it through the command specified in the instructions, it reached one of the last steps and gave me an error. There are also no instructions on how to adapt it to your docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts and hints from the question:

[mosquitto-go-auth with postgres authorization error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77929179)

I managed to customize docker-compose to suit my needs:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres:14.8-alpine3.18
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "max_connections=50"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_buffers=1GB"
      - "-c"
      - "effective_cache_size=4GB"
      - "-c"
      - "work_mem=16MB"
      - "-c"
      - "maintenance_work_mem=512MB"
      - "-c"
      - "random_page_cost=1.1"
      - "-c"
      - "temp_file_limit=10GB"
      - "-c"
      - "log_min_duration_statement=200ms"
      - "-c"
      - "idle_in_transaction_session_timeout=10s"
      - "-c"
      - "lock_timeout=1s"
      - "-c"
      - "statement_timeout=60s"
      - "-c"
      - "shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements"
      - "-c"
      - "pg_stat_statements.max=10000"
      - "-c"
      - "pg_stat_statements.track=all"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ../2. Init Database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mosquitto/init-mqtt-auth-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mqtt-auth-db.sh
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U ${DATABASE_USER} -d ${DATABASE_NAME}"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 4G
    networks:
      - postgres

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:7.2
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PG_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PG_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: "False"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1G
    networks:
      - postgres

  auth-plugin:
    image: iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf:/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
      - ./mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log:/mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
      - data:/mosquitto/data
    ports:
      - target: 1883
        published: 1883
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 9001
        published: 9001
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - postgres


volumes:
  postgres-data:
  pgadmin-data:
  data:
    name: "mqtt-broker-data"

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

  postgres-data:
```