# mosquitto-go-auth with postgres authorization error

Tags: postgresql, mqtt, mosquitto

I installed mosquito broker and the postgres database. Downloaded and configured the mosquitto-go-auth plugin.

mosquitto status:

```
Loading config file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/go-auth.conf
time="2024-02-02T21:00:08+03:00" level=info msg="backend registered: Postgres"
time="2024-02-02T21:00:08+03:00" level=info msg="registered acl checker: postgres"
time="2024-02-02T21:00:08+03:00" level=info msg="registered user checker: postgres"
time="2024-02-02T21:00:08+03:00" level=info msg="registered superuser checker: postgres"
фtime="2024-02-02T21:00:08+03:00" level=info msg="No cache set."
time="2024-02-02T21:01:00+03:00" level=debug msg="checking user Frogger with backend Postgres"
time="2024-02-02T21:09:57+03:00" level=debug msg="checking user Frogger with backend Postgres"
```

mosquitto.conf

```
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

conf.d:

```
listener 1883
auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/go-auth.so
auth_opt_log_level debug

require_certificate false
# postgress options:

auth_opt_backends postgres

auth_opt_pg_host 127.0.0.1
auth_opt_pg_port 5432
auth_opt_pg_dbname go_auth_test
auth_opt_pg_user postgres
auth_opt_pg_password postgres

# hash options:
auth_opt_pg_hasher bcrypt

#auth_opt_pg_hasher argon2id
auth_opt_pg_hasher_salt_size 16           # salt bytes length
#auth_opt_pg_hasher_iterations 3           # number of iterations
#auth_opt_pg_hasher_keylen 64              # key length
#auth_opt_pg_hasher_memory 4096            # amount of memory (in kibibytes) to use
#auth_opt_pg_hasher_parallelism            # degree of parallelism (i.e. number of threads)


#ssl
auth_opt_pg_sslmode disable
#auth_opt_pg_sslcert /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosquitto.crt
#auth_opt_pg_sslkey /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosquitto.key
#auth_opt_pg_sslrootcert /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosquittoroot.crt


auth_opt_pg_connect_tries 5
auth_opt_pg_userquery select password_hash from "test_user" where username = $1 limit 1;
#auth_opt_pg_userquery select password_hash from "test_user" where username = "$1" limit 1;
auth_opt_pg_superquery select count(*) from "user" where username = $1 and is_admin = true
```

mosquitto.log:

```
1706896808: mosquitto version 2.0.18 starting
1706896808: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1706896808: Loading plugin: /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/go-auth.so
1706896808:  ├── Username/password checking enabled.
1706896808:  ├── TLS-PSK checking enabled.
1706896808:  └── Extended authentication not enabled.
1706896808: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1706896808: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1706896808: mosquitto version 2.0.18 running
1706896860: New connection from 127.0.0.1:58676 on port 1883.
1706896860: Client auto-9013899F-0297-0F48-2C18-26A3DF7734F8 disconnected, not authorised.
1706897397: New connection from 127.0.0.1:46014 on port 1883.
1706897397: Client auto-8BCBE732-65A6-ADD8-EE81-6120DFAD448E disconnected, not authorised.
1706897597: New connection from 127.0.0.1:54366 on port 1883.
1706897597: Client auto-2DFF5060-31E2-C126-1573-42CA3529E290 disconnected, not authorised.
1706898022: New connection from 127.0.0.1:59730 on port 1883.
1706898022: Client auto-1527B628-3033-9B8D-3044-1F131D8D24E9 disconnected, not authorised.
```

postgres.log:

```
2024-02-02 21:20:22.786 MSK [73857] postgres@go_auth_test DEBUG:  parse <unnamed>: select password_hash from "test_user" where username = $1 limit 1;
2024-02-02 21:20:22.786 MSK [73857] postgres@go_auth_test STATEMENT:  select password_hash from "test_user" where username = $1 limit 1;
2024-02-02 21:20:22.787 MSK [73857] postgres@go_auth_test LOG:  duration: 0.132 ms  parse <unnamed>: select password_hash from "test_user" where username = $1 limit 1;
2024-02-02 21:20:22.787 MSK [73857] postgres@go_auth_test DEBUG:  bind <unnamed> to <unnamed>
2024-02-02 21:20:22.787 MSK [73857] postgres@go_auth_test LOG:  duration: 0.125 ms  bind <unnamed>: select password_hash from "test_user" where username = $1 limit 1;
2024-02-02 21:20:22.787 MSK [73857] postgres@go_auth_test DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'Frogger'
2024-02-02 21:20:22.787 MSK [73857] postgres@go_auth_test LOG:  duration: 0.020 ms  execute <unnamed>: select password_hash from "test_user" where username = $1 limit 1;
2024-02-02 21:20:22.787 MSK [73857] postgres@go_auth_test DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'Frogger'
2024-02-02 21:20:28.452 MSK [73839] DEBUG:  received inquiry for database 0
2024-02-02 21:20:28.452 MSK [73839] DEBUG:  writing stats file "/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2024-02-02 21:20:28.452 MSK [73839] DEBUG:  writing stats file "/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp/db_0.stat"
2024-02-02 21:20:28.469 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2024-02-02 21:20:28.472 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  autovacuum: processing database "go_auth_test"
2024-02-02 21:20:28.473 MSK [73839] DEBUG:  received inquiry for database 16385
2024-02-02 21:20:28.473 MSK [73839] DEBUG:  writing stats file "/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp/global.stat"
2024-02-02 21:20:28.473 MSK [73839] DEBUG:  writing stats file "/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp/db_16385.stat"
2024-02-02 21:20:28.473 MSK [73839] DEBUG:  writing stats file "/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp/db_0.stat"
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  test_acl: vac: 0 (threshold 50), ins: 0 (threshold 1000), anl: 0 (threshold 50)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  test_user: vac: 0 (threshold 50), ins: 3 (threshold 1000), anl: 3 (threshold 50)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_statistic: vac: 0 (threshold 131), ins: 0 (threshold 1081), anl: 0 (threshold 91)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_type: vac: 0 (threshold 170), ins: 4 (threshold 1120), anl: 4 (threshold 110)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_authid: vac: 1 (threshold 52), ins: 1 (threshold 1002), anl: 2 (threshold 51)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_attribute: vac: 2 (threshold 644), ins: 40 (threshold 1594), anl: 42 (threshold 347)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_proc: vac: 0 (threshold 690), ins: 36 (threshold 1640), anl: 36 (threshold 370)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_class: vac: 3 (threshold 129), ins: 6 (threshold 1079), anl: 9 (threshold 90)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_attrdef: vac: 0 (threshold 50), ins: 2 (threshold 1000), anl: 2 (threshold 50)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_constraint: vac: 0 (threshold 71), ins: 3 (threshold 1021), anl: 3 (threshold 61)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_index: vac: 0 (threshold 81), ins: 2 (threshold 1031), anl: 2 (threshold 66)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_operator: vac: 0 (threshold 211), ins: 0 (threshold 1161), anl: 0 (threshold 130)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_opclass: vac: 0 (threshold 85), ins: 0 (threshold 1035), anl: 0 (threshold 68)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_am: vac: 0 (threshold 51), ins: 0 (threshold 1001), anl: 0 (threshold 51)
2024-02-02 21:20:28.484 MSK [73923] DEBUG:  pg_amop: vac: 0 (threshold 239), ins: 0 (threshold 1189), anl: 0 (threshold 144)
```

go_user_test.db:

```
 id | username |                        password_hash                         | is_admin 
----+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------
  1 | Frog     | 1234                                                         | f
  2 | Frogger  | $2a$06$trR7wxzdqvdbm/hFOxYChuXoyy2SXkbOBexssLQRbEpjaKP10QmLO | f
  3 | Frogger  | $2a$16$TKu7U8IBkMuYg0KVH6/EzOheUA53D6izmHhArQMCFD8qJ9gEXVXDO | f
  4 | Frogger  | $2b$12$skzMpzs80BukRP5DEQsaUOfRU5vZuwpMIS.WuASuXM7ApOP6kbhAi | f
```

how I insert data in database:

```
INSERT INTO test_user (id,username, password_hash, is_admin)
VALUES (3,'Frogger', crypt('1234', gen_salt('bf', 16)), false);
```

command to connect:

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t test -u "Frogger" -P "1234"
```

Every time I try to connect, I get an error:

```
Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.
```

and after i use command `sudo systemctl status mosquitto`:

```
error: received null username or password for unpwd check
```

However, I am sure that the password and login is correct (I showed how I enter the password into the database).
I can't understand why I'm getting an error, please help me

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with the above (and your hash's work fine with my `mosquitto-go-auth` setup running under docker). The error you are getting would be triggered by a request without a username/password (e.g. `mosquitto_sub.exe -t test`); I have been unable to duplicate the `null username or password` issue any other way).

Comment: @Brits To my surprise, the problem was solved when I renamed the password_hash column to password. And I started using the postgres user.

Comment: @Brits can you help me with configuring mosquitto-go-auth under docker compose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, the cause of your initial issue is unclear (having an underscore in the field name should not be an issue). To help you present an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (and possibly point you towards a solution) here is the docker compose setup I created to (roughly!) replicate your setup (this is not fit for production use!).

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    mosquitto:
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
        image: iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth        
        volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: ./mosquittocfg
          target: /etc/mosquitto
        ports:
        - target: 1883
          published: 1883
          protocol: tcp
          mode: host  
        logging:
            driver: json-file
            options:
                max-size: 5m      
    db:        
        image: postgres:15-alpine        
        restart: unless-stopped
        healthcheck:
           test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d authdb -U authuser"]
           interval: 5s
           timeout: 5s
           retries: 20
           start_period: 30s
        volumes:
        - type: bind
          source: ./dbinit
          target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_DB: authdb
            POSTGRES_USER: authuser
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: authpassword
        ports:
        - target: 5432
          published: 5432
          protocol: tcp
          mode: host
        logging:
            driver: json-file
            options:
                max-size: 5m
```

**./dbinit/goauthtest.sql**

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;

create table mqtt_user (
   username TEXT NOT NULL,
   password_hash TEXT NOT NULL,
   is_admin BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

insert into mqtt_user(username, password_hash, is_admin) VALUES ('Frogger', crypt('1234', gen_salt('bf', 16)), false)
```

**./mosquittocfg/mosquitto.conf**

```
log_type  all
listener 1883

auth_plugin /mosquitto/go-auth.so
auth_opt_log_level debug

# postgress options:
auth_opt_backends postgres
auth_opt_pg_host db
auth_opt_pg_port 5432
auth_opt_pg_dbname authdb
auth_opt_pg_user authuser
auth_opt_pg_password authpassword

auth_opt_pg_hasher bcrypt

auth_opt_pg_sslmode disable

auth_opt_pg_connect_tries 5
auth_opt_pg_userquery select password_hash from mqtt_user where username = $1 limit 1;
```

Comment: Yes! You've been very helpful. I didn't take your docker compose.yml. Just take a part of the block with 

``` image: iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth ```

And for the rest, I left my settings, only removing the line about go-auth.so since mine overlapped the one that already exists in the container. 
Thanks to you, everything turned out fine! Thank you very much.

Can you give recommendations on how to configure containers in docker more correctly?

Comment: "Can you give recommendations on how to configure containers in docker more correctly?" - not really; every container is different (so you need to read the docs; and sometimes look at the way the image is built). One thing that can be handy is running up a shell in the container (e.g. `docker compose exec mosquitto /bin/sh`) and having a look around (check that config files are as you expect, try running services etc).